# Refresh scrollAreaWidget from PyQt5

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5

I want to refresh the **scrollAreaWidget** so that new buttons added appear on the list by the side.
Buttons that I manually set in before running the code work fine, but new ones don't appear.

Here is the entire code,
The area of interest should be the function **SetList**

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(1500, 1000)
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle("Test")

        self.centralwidget = QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")

        self.lineEditName = QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineEditName.setGeometry(QRect(20, 90, 860, 40))
        self.lineEditName.setFont(QFont("Times new roman",15))
        self.lineEditName.setText("")
        self.lineEditName.setToolTip("Name")
        self.lineEditName.setPlaceholderText("Name")

        self.pushButtonAdd = QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButtonAdd.setGeometry(QRect(20, 800, 120, 50))
        self.pushButtonAdd.setFont(QFont("Times new roman",20))
        self.pushButtonAdd.setText("Add")
        self.pushButtonAdd.clicked.connect(self.AddContact)

        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

    def AddContact(self):
        if self.lineEditName.text() != "":   
            Names.append(self.lineEditName.text())
            self.SetList()
            print(f"Success - Added {self.lineEditName.text()}")
        else:
            print("Error")

    def SetList(self):
        self.scrollArea = QScrollArea(self.centralwidget)
        self.scrollArea.setGeometry(QRect(1000, 90, 400, 680))
        self.scrollArea.setWidgetResizable(True)

        self.scrollAreaWidgetContents = QWidget()
        self.scrollAreaWidgetContents.setGeometry(QRect(0, 0, 400, 680))
        self.scrollAreaWidgetContents.setObjectName("scrollAreaWidgetContents")
        self.verticalLayout = QVBoxLayout(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents)

        Names.sort()
        for name in Names:
            self.pushButtonList = QPushButton(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents)
            self.pushButtonList.setText(name)
            self.pushButtonList.setFont(QFont("Times new roman",14))
            self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.pushButtonList)
            self.scrollArea.setWidget(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    Names = ["Thor", "Loki"]
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    ui.SetList()
    MainWindow.show()
    
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Unfortunately, your code has too many and broad issues to be considered as acceptable and useful to anybody else. The main problem is that every time you add a contact, you are actually creating a **new** scroll area by calling `SetList()`, which obviously doesn't make any sense. But that's just the tip of the iceberg, since you got other major issues: 1. you're not setting a main [layout manager](//doc.qt.io/qt-5/layout.html) for the central widget; 2. you're editing a pyuic generated file, despite the clear warning that file had about *not editing unless you knew what you're doing* »

Comment: » which you ignored and removed (you should follow the official guidelines about [using Designer](//www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt5/designer.html) instead); 3. you're indiscriminately using global references (`Names`) ignoring their context, while global objects should always be used with extreme care (and usually avoided at all as general rule, unless you *do* know what you're doing); 4. you're using capitalized names for functions/methods, while such style should only be used for classes/constants instead (see the [Style Guide for Python Code](//python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008)).

Comment: That was harsh... But extremely true.
I will take more care in the future and while re-creating this code
Thanks for the heads up